# Detect Vagrant up in vagrantfile

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

In my `vagrantfile` I use two lines of rudy code to get the username and password from the console and pass it on to the shell script for creating an additional user account instead of the default `vagrant`

This works well for `vagrant up` but it beats me by prompting the same when I run any other vagrant commands like `vagrant status`. Is there a way to catch if the vagrant file is called with `up` command?

```rb
require 'io/console'

print "Please enter username: "
@username = STDIN.gets

print "Please enter password: "
@password = STDIN.noecho(&:gets)

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/debian10"
  ["Node 01"].each do |node_name|
    config.vm.define node_name do |node|
        node.vm.provision "shell" do |p|
            p.args = [@username, @password]
            p.path = "create_user.sh"
        end
    end
  end
end
```

---

UPDATE

After @Matt Schuchard's suggestion, I've tried triggers; However, the global variables that are captured inside the trigger block are not shared with the place where I pass them into the shell script (`p.args = [@username, @password]`)

```rb
config.trigger.before :up do |trigger|
  if @credential_captured == nil # I've used this to prevent executing the following block per each vm
    print "Please enter username: "
    @username = STDIN.gets

    print "Please enter password: "
    @password = STDIN.noecho(&:gets)
    @credential_captured = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you looking for triggers: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers?

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard, I've looked into triggers, but it seems they are run in per VM context; and are not shared among multiple VM contexts :(. I've updated my question with the findings.

Answer (score 1):

### Sprinkle Some Plain Ruby into the Vagrantfile

The best practice would really be to put an idempotent [provisioning block](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning) at the end that picks up your information from the environment or some other fixed location rather than trying to do this as interactive user input within the Vagrantfile. However, if you *really* want to do it the way you're doing it, just remember that a Vagrantfile is mostly just a DSL on top of Ruby.

You can get the status of a given virtual machine with `vagrant status`. For a single node, you could just wrap your current prompts at the top in a conditional. For example:

```
# assuming a single node named "default"
if %x(vagrant status default) =~ /running/
  # prompt here
end
```

If you're running multiple nodes, then I'd suggest wrapping your prompts into a method and moving your conditional down into the body of the shell provisioning block you already have. For example:

```rb
def prompt_user
  # prompt here
end

# ...

if `vagrant status #{node_name}` =~ running
  prompt_user unless @username && @password
  node.vm.provision 'shell' do |p|
    # provision your node here
  end
end
```

There are likely ways to make this code more efficient, and probably other ways to do what you want, but this approach is fairly straightforward and should at least get you headed in the right direction.